# Grid column defined with vw unit minus a pixel amount?

Tags: css, css-grid, viewport-units

I have a grid with `grid-template-columns: 30vw 20vw 30vw;`

I'd like to subtract a fixed pixel amount from two of those widths, e.g. I'd like the first column to have a calculated width of `30vw - 1px`.

What I'd like is something like (below code doesn't work):

`grid-template-columns: calc(30vw-1px) 20vw calc(30vw-1px);`

This is so I can get a border on the outside of the grid that still works as the viewport scales (would prefer not to define the border in vw units also - want it fixed width of 1px).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `calc()` arguments are invalid.

You have this:

```
grid-template-columns: calc(30vw-1px) 20vw calc(30vw-1px)
```

You need to do this:

```
grid-template-columns: calc(30vw - 1px) 20vw calc(30vw - 1px)
```

*From MDN:*

> [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
>
> The `+` and `-` operators must be surrounded by whitespace.
>
> For instance, `calc(50% -8px)` will be parsed as a percentage followed
>   by a negative length—an invalid expression—while `calc(50% - 8px)` is
>   a percentage followed by a subtraction operator and a length.
>
> Likewise, `calc(8px + -50%)` is treated as a length followed by an
>   addition operator and a negative percentage.
>
> The `*` and `/` operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for
>   consistency is both allowed and recommended.

Comment: thanks @Michael_B with this, my nested grid with fixed pixel amounts of padding left and right, fits perfectly in the parent grid cell defined in vw units, as it scales!